# Why do I get a compilation error when returning i after enhanced for loop?

Tags: java

I'm learning Java and I don't understand why I get an error.

```
public static int sum(ArrayList<Integer> list) {

    for(int i : list){
        i += i;
    }

    return i;
}
```

I fixed error by making a new sum variable but I still would like to understand why I can't return i. Is the scope of i limited to the for loop?  I wonder why its not allowed it would be useful to use it outside.

Comment: where are you adding i, you cant add i to itself, just create an int outside and add to it

Comment: @SeekAddo: *"you cant add i to itself"* You *can*, it just doesn't survive long. :-)

Comment: yea but he cant access it outside of the loop @T.J.Crowder

Answer (score 2):

> Why do I get a compilation error when returning i after enhanced for loop?

Because the `i` declared in the `for` loop is scoped only to the `for` loop; you cannot access it outside the `for` loop.

You said you've already fixed it by adding a new `sum` variable, so I assume you ended up with something like this:

```
public static int sum(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i : list){
        sum += i;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

I would suggest also that you use `List<Integer>` rather than `ArrayList<Integer>`:

```
public static int sum(List<Integer> list) {
    // Here ----------^

    // ...
}
```

In general, code to the least restrictive type.

---

Separately, modifications to the value of `i` within the loop body will just be overwritten by the value for the next iteration that the loop itself sets. Consider:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
list.add(3);
for (int i : list){
    System.out.println("before: " + i);
    i += i;
    System.out.println("after: " + i);
}
```

Outputs

```
before: 1
after: 2
before: 2
after: 4
before: 3
after: 6
```

Notice how regardless what you do to `i` in the loop body, it gets set by the loop itself on the next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

`i` is only accessible within the scope of your `enhanced for loop` that is the reason why you can't return it within your method.

Warning, you're also using `i+=i` which does not do anything special since each time you loop, `i` represents another index of your `ArrayList`.

This is the equavilent of using the following code

```
public static int sum(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    int counter = 0;
    while (counter < list.size()) {
        int i = list.get(counter); // You're creating a new variable at each iteration so it doesn't affect anything for the next loop.
        i += i;
    }
    return i;
}
```

A solution would be to use a temporary variable such as `sum` for example. Check the answer below.

```
public static int sum(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i : list){
        sum+=i;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

---

[java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8)

Another solution, if you're using [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) would be to use `IntStream#sum()`

```
public static int sum(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    return list.stream().mapToInt(i->i).sum();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I managed to fix it before commenting. But I didn't spot the flaw in the old code that meant i overwrites each iteration.

Comment: @user6480616 I added a concrete example of why it isn't working.